# MySQL query delivers unwanted data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search through my database with this query:

```
SELECT jobunique, jobtypeunique, joblat, joblng FROM job WHERE

        jobdeleted = 0

        AND

        jobpayed = 1

        AND

        (LOWER(jobtitle) LIKE '%taxi%'
        OR LOWER(jobmaincategory) LIKE '%taxi%'
        OR LOWER(jobsubcategory) LIKE '%taxi%'
        OR LOWER(jobdescription) LIKE '%taxi%'
        OR LOWER(jobcountry) LIKE '%taxi%')

        AND

        (
            jobbusiness = 1 AND jobstartdate <= CURDATE() AND jobenddate >= CURDATE()
        ) OR
        ( 
            jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 0 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobdateadded >= (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
        ) OR
        (
            jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobstartdate >= CURDATE()
        ) OR
        (
            jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 1 AND jobenddate <= CURDATE()
        )
```

But regardless of whether there is `"taxi"` in one of the fields, I receive all the rows where `jobbusiness = 0`. Can someone please explain to me why? Thank you

Comment: Regular expressions in MySQL by default are case insensitive. So you can actually get rid of that `LOWER`. I am actually tempted to use CONCAT_WS instead of using multiple LIKE operators. Something like -----                                                                                         AND CONCAT_WS(',',jobtitle,jobmaincategory,jobsubcategory,Jobdescription,jobcountry) REGEXP 'taxi';

Comment: @RajatS.Subedi - thank you. I never heard of that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra set of parentheses around your final group of `OR`ed conditions otherwise the last 3 conditions just get `OR`ed independently of the rest of the conditions. Note that you don't need `()` around `AND`ed conditions as `AND` takes precedence over `OR` anyway. Changing the last part of your `WHERE` condition to this should fix the problem:

```
AND (
        jobbusiness = 1 AND jobstartdate <= CURDATE() AND jobenddate >= CURDATE()
    OR
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 0 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobdateadded >= (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
    OR
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 0 AND jobstartdate >= CURDATE()
    OR
        jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 1 AND jobfixedenddate = 1 AND jobenddate <= CURDATE()
)
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, but I want them to be "AND OR", Wouldn´t I need the parentheses between the OR conditions for that? - I don´t get it yet fully... :)

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen `(a AND b AND c) OR (d AND e AND f)` is the same as `a AND b AND c OR d AND e AND f` because `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so the grouping inside the parentheses happens first regardless of whether they are there or not. It's the same reasoning behind putting `()` around all your `LIKE` conditions.

Comment: Hmm, but - I want all rows where jobbusiness = 1 AND... - AND I want all rows where jobbusiness = 0 AND... - So, with my way of understanding - and I´m a newbee - I don´t get what business of "OR" is there... It should be: "AND ((jobbusiness = 1 AND jobstartdate <=....) AND (jobbusiness = 0 AND jobfixedstartdate = 0...))"

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen in your case the `AND I want all rows` is better expressed `AS WELL AS all rows` so you are *adding* rows, and that is what `OR` does.

Comment: Mhm, okay. Thank you that helped. :)